# Replacing font tags with their HTML contents

Tags: html, haskell

I am doing this homework now, but I do not have any idea. Could someone help me?

Given the following data type for representing HTML:

```
type HTML = [HTML_element]
data HTML_element = HTML_text String
                  | HTML_font Font_tag HTML
                  | HTML_p HTML
                  | HTML_ul [HTML]
                  | HTML_ol [HTML]

data Font_tag = Font_size Int
              | Font_face String
              | Font_color Font_color

data Font_color = Colour_name String
                | Hex Int
                | RGB Int Int Int
```

write a Haskell function:

```
strip_font_tags :: HTML -> HTML
```

which removes all font tags, replacing them with their HTML contents.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck writing your function?

Comment: If you have a single `HTML_element`, e.g. `HTML_font Font_tag html_contents`, how do you replace it with its HTML contents? And if you have an `HTML_element` that isn't `HTML_font`, do you need to do anything to it?

Answer (score 5):

I think everybody else here is missing the point of the exercise. Here was my thought process after interpreting the problem; perhaps this can guide you a bit.

I want to think about operating on one single `HTML_element` at a time, so I want a function that has type `HTML_element -> ???` at some point; figuring out what `???` might be will be a huge first step. A first stab would be to choose `HTML_element` for `???`, but that doesn't quite work, since the contents of a font tag is `HTML`, not `HTML_element`. Hm... what is `HTML` again? Ah, yes, `type HTML = [HTML_element]`! So, actually, I could return an `HTML` in each case; in the non-font cases, I can just wrap up the single element in a singleton list.

Hm, but now what? I wonder [if there's a function that does just what I want](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=(html_element+-%3E+%5Bhtml_element%5D)+-%3E+(%5Bhtml_element%5D+-%3E+%5Bhtml_element%5D)) now that I've written the per-element function...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easy way is to replace `HTML_element` with another `HTML_element` — this is a structure-preserving transformation, and you could probably change your data a little, write a `Functor` instance, and then just use `fmap` — your mapping is "if it's `HTML_font _ x`, return e.g. `HTML_p x`; if not, return as-is".

Here's that expressed with SYB:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Generics

data Element
    = Text String
    | Font [Element]
    | Para [Element]
    deriving (Show, Typeable, Data)

-- replace Font with Para
replace' :: Element -> Element
replace' (Font x) = Para x
replace' x = x

-- top-level transformation
-- replace this with manual recursion and you're set
replace :: Element -> Element
replace = everywhere (mkT replace')

example =
    Para [
        Text "1",
        Font [
            Text "2.1",
            Para [
                Text "2.2.1",
                Font [Text "2.2.2"]
            ]
        ],
        Text "3"
    ]
```

In GHCi:

```
[*Main]
> replace example
Loading package syb-0.3.6.1 ... linking ... done.
Para [Text "1",Para [Text "2.1",Para [Text "2.2.1",Para [Text "2.2.2"]]],Text "3"]
it :: Element
```

If you want to completely eliminate those elements, you might be able to map everything into lists and then concat them. Try to figure it out on your own.